fabric.js-When to use "setCoords" method?
In fabric.js, when should the 'setCoords' method be used? Is it necessary to use 'setCoords' method after the 'set' method? For example, if I use the 'set' method to change the width of a rectangle, should I also use 'setCoords'?

Read this.  When you change (almost) any attribute of a rectangle, you need setCoords.  http://fabricjs.com/fabric-gotchas
